# Why is the constructor called twice in my program?

Tags: c++

The constructor of the World object in the following program is called twice.

header file :

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#include "World.h"

class Game
{
    public:
        Game();
    private:
        World world;
};
```

cpp file :-

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game()
{
    world = World();
}
```

Header file of World class :-

```
#ifndef WORLD_H
#define WORLD_H

class World
{
    public:
        World();
};
#endif // WORLD_H
```

cpp file of the World class:-

```
#include "World.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

World::World()
{
    cout<<"i am going to print twice"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: [SSCCE](http://www,sscce.org) please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each member is automatically initialised before the constructor begins; since you don't include `world` in the initialiser list, it's default-initialised at that point, calling your constructor.

Then you create a temporary object to assign to it; that causes the second constructor call. There's no need to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Your class definition says `Game` has a `World` member so creating a Game instance will automatically create a World. Then in your constructor you are assigning `this->world` a second time and creating a second instance, so that is the second call.

You can leave out the line in your constructor entirely. If you have arguments that you wish to pass to initialize `World` then you can do

```
Game::Game(someArg) : world(someArg){

}
```

Comment: Why call the copy constructor of class `World` when you can directly pass `someArg` to `World::World`?

Answer (score 1):

When `Game` is constructed `World` is also default constructed as it's a member of `World`, that's the fist.

The second time is in `Game::Game`: you construct a temporary `World` object and assign it to `World::world` is with the following code.

```
world = World();
```

What you probably want is this:

```
Game::Game()
{
}
```

You don't need the default construction and assignment.

Comment: You have to be quick around here it seems :)